# MvvmCross (iOS): sample throws runtime exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, runtimeexception

I'm trying out MvvmCross (6.4.1) and following the approach in the readme.txt of the installed Nuget package using the sample mentioned [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/ContentFiles/):

> - Core project -
>
>   1. Add an App class to the root folder (See Core/App.cs.pp in sample files).
>   2. Add a ViewModels folder to the root of the project and add at least one ViewModel class to this folder (See Core/HomeViewModel.cs.pp in sample files).
> - iOS projects (ignore if not building for iOS) -
>
>   1. Inside AppDelegate.cs, change the AppDelegate class to inherit from MvxApplicationDelegate, Core.App> instead of ApplicationDelegate (See iOS/AppDelegate.cs.pp in sample files).
>   2. Still inside AppDelegate.cs, delete all the pre-populated methods to leave a blank AppDelegate class.
>   3. Add a Views folder to the root of the project and add at least one View class to this folder to correspond to the ViewModel class in the Core project (See iOS/HomeView.cs.pp in sample files).
>   4. Add a new iOS Interface Builder layout (XIB) or StoryBoard file to the Views folder to correspond to the View created in the previous step. (See iOS/HomeView.xib.pp in sample files).

Only difference I'm using a storyboard instead of a xib. I've adjusted the Info.plist accordingly. Even though the readme says that the solution should run I get a runtime exception in Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIAplication.cs:

[image: runtime exception]

Is there anything missing in the readme to get this simple solution running?

Comment: Have you tried using XIBs instead of a storyboard? Did that work? Also at what point in the lifecycle do you get that exception?

Comment: @Saamer when trying to use a XIB I just get a blank white screen. When using the storyboard the exception happens immediately in UIApplicationMain

Comment: Isn’t that intended behaviour for it to be a white screen? Or did you already place items on the XIB?

Comment: Ok did you remember to add an MvxFromStoryboard attribute over your View class, indicating the name of the storyboard file as mentioned here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/ios/ios-user-interfaces-approaches

Comment: Something also seems weird. I don’t understand why the files are names “.cs.pp” in the github repo you shared.

Comment: I can't tell you why they added a file ending of ".pp" in the GitHub - you'd have to ask the contributors. However in the meantime I got another sample (TipCalc.iOS) to work with XIB. In order for this to work I had to delete several entries in the Info.plist: UIApplicationSceneManifest, Main storyboard file base name and Main storyboard file base name (iPad). Also the Main Interface entry had to be left empty.

Comment: Ok awesome. Yeah I think that first sample was messed up. Just open an issue

Comment: I've also checked out handling storyboards: it's the same problem with the storyboard entries in the Info.plist. Once you delete them (see above) everything works smoothly.

Comment: Oh nice ! How did you find that out? Put that as an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me several days to figure this out I'll provide my findings regarding this issue. The same solution also works for the [TipCalc.iOS tutorial](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinios-ui-project?scroll=1680). 
My settings are:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.2
- VS for Mac Community 8.3.11
- Xcode 11.3

I had to delete several entries in the Info.plist regarding storyboards:

[image: entries in Info.plist]

After I deleted those keys including the subkeys the demos mentioned above worked - both for XIBs and storyboards.